# connection error while connecting python to elasticsearch

Tags: python, mysql, elasticsearch, kibana

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': '192.168.7.101', 'port': 9200}])
es
res = es.search(index='opm', body = {"query": {"match": {"event_country_name":"Singapore"}}}, request_timeout=30)
```

The code above gives the following error:

> ConnectionError: ConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) caused
>   by: NewConnectionError(: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError
>   10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond)

It was working earlier. I don't know what happened and it is now unreachable. I tried to update the pip. Then I downgraded to see if the issue was related to it. Nothing happened. I even tried to uninstall and reinstall the python and also urllib3.

Please help me out.

The full error message is:

```html
GET http://192.168.7.101:9200/opm/_search [status:N/A request:21.017s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021CBDA8FF28>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
GET http://192.168.7.101:9200/opm/_search [status:N/A request:21.020s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021CBDA8FF98>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
GET http://192.168.7.101:9200/opm/_search [status:N/A request:21.016s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021CBDAB20B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
GET http://192.168.7.101:9200/opm/_search [status:N/A request:21.022s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 171, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 79, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 69, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 180, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021CBDAB2160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-37571f0445fd>", line 1, in <module>
    res = es.search(index='opm', body = {"query": {"match": {"event_country_name":"Singapore"}}}, request_timeout=30)

  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 660, in search
    doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)

  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)

  File "E:\Data Science\pyWork\PyProjects\Program\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 181, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError('N/A', str(e), e)

ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021CBDAB2160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021CBDAB2160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)
```

Comment: This is a timeout error, it means your program wasnt able to reach the url `http://192.168.7.101:9200`. What do you get when you try to access this URL on your browser?

Comment: What was the answer to fix this?

Comment: how did you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this kind of error is because of proxy setting. if you use proxy client please make sure its up and running.

Comment: but I am not using any proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is client side (python connecting to Elastic Search server), but reading the message it seems that the issue is with the Elastic Search server itself. It doesn't really look like a programming issue. If you can access the Elastic Search server ensure it is running. If it is running on the same machine, ensure that the machine ip is still the same (a DHCP renew can change the address). Also check that your network connection is working.